# How to set text from an edittext from another class

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

In my application the user presses the TextView and it brings up an intent over the screen where the user enters the text they want.

Here is the case statement

```
case R.id.Weapon:
    W = new Intent(WeapDescrip.this, PopUp.class);
    String WeaponName = getSavedObject();
    Weapon.setText("Weapon: " + WeaponName);
break;
```

and here is getSavedObject()

```
private String getSavedObject() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(W);
        String SavedObject = (String) PopUp.savedObject;
        return SavedObject;
}
```

and here is the PopUp class

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        savedObject = etSave.getText();
        //finish();
        Intent n = new Intent(PopUp.this, WeapDescrip.class);
        startActivity(n);
        }
    }
```

when it goes back to the weapdescrip class the text view doesn't change at all

any help is worth while thanks in advance.

Comment: have you ever heard of startActivityForResult? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult

Comment: http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12186/android-startactivityforresult-example/ here is a tutorial for startActivityForResult